# how to set sentences as a option in set /p = command [batch]

Tags: string, batch-file, variables

I know its probably a newbie question but if [something](in the below code) is more than 1 word it would just close and not send me to [correct]. I don't know if there is a way the specify the user in inputting a multi word string or if it is a simple 1 word input.

```
set/p something= input:  
if %something% equ goto correct
if %something% neq goto incorrect
```

I suspect the spaces are confusing the code and having it think that instead of reading [goto correct] its trying to read the second word as the command. any fix's would be helpful even if its a little advanced.

Comment: They're strings not integers, so the comparison operator should be `==`. In addition, you want to compare the input with an expected string, so you need to include that string in the comparison. The two examples you've posted should therefore read as `If /I "%something%" == "Expected String" GoTo correct` and `If /I Not "%something%" == "Expected String" GoTo incorrect`

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the variable in quotes so that it detects it as a string when you compare it in the if.

Example:

```
set /p something="Input any text for me: "
echo Output: %something%

if "%something%" EQU "Hello World" echo OK
if "%something%" NEQ "Hello World" echo NOT OK
```